# Auto process POST and GET in PHP

Tags: php, function, post, get

Is there a way or piece of code that looks for POST and GET data and turns them into normal variables?

I mean it to make:

```
$_POST["hello"] = "Wow."
```

into

```
$hello = "Wow."
```

But also be able to do it automatically and with many POSTS and GETS, so like this:

```
$_POST["name"]="John"; 
$_GET["email"]="john@john.com"; 
$_POST["sex"]="male";
```

into

```
$name="John"; 
$email="john@john.com"; 
$sex="male";
```

I know the second example is impossible (you can't get GET and POST data at the same time (or so I know), but the idea is that whether the page gets a GET or a POST variable it should turn it into variables automatically.

So is there a function or something that can help me?

Comment: they are normal variables in the first place.

Comment: A form with method POST and its action has GET variables can send both GET and POST variables...just saying. EG: <form method="post" action="/?foo=bar">

Comment: You're asking for `register_globals`. Bad OP! Plus, how about POSTing to `/foo.php?bar=baz`? Then you would have $_GET and $_POST.

Comment: But that's deprecated..and removed in 5.4!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [extract()](http://php.net/extract): `extract($_REQUEST);` (`$_REQUEST` combines `$_POST` and `$_GET`)

But I would consider it as **bad practice**, because it adds some black magic to your code which can lead to unpredictable situations. Also it's easily exploitable:

Consider that you have a variable: `$secret = 100;` which nobody should change.
Now comes a kinky user and injects following POST variable in a form submit: `$_POST['secret'] = 200;`
There you have the exploitation!

Comment: Thanks. I'm sticking to the old practice then. I was just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), It works for all type of arrays.

```
<?php

/* Suppose that $var_array is an array returned from
   wddx_deserialize */

$size = "large";
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

echo "$color, $size, $shape, $wddx_size\n";

?>
```

> Edit: I wouldn't consider as a good practise though

Comment: very dangerous with user submitted data

Comment: indeed, I believe its not a good practise specially with user submitted data

Comment: perhaps not even suggesting a bad idea is better than saying its bad after the fact

Comment: I think if you show how it is achieved but also give an elaborated reason why not to use it, is not bad.

Comment: he wanted an answer I gave him an answer and suggested it as not a good practise well, I would leave the rest of the exploring to him. I do agree with Dagon but Atleast he now knows such functions exist and he also knows that he should not use it for user submitted data, its better than not knowing anything isn't it

Comment: Thanks. I will not use it then.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old post, but here's an answer if anyone is looking.

There's a safe way to automate this without using extract on $_POST, which is a security risk as mentioned. This function will work for $_POST if you feed it a simple array of keys you expect.

```
function post_params($arr){

    $pp = array();
    foreach($arr AS $key){
        if(isset($_POST[$key])){
            $pp[$key] = $_POST[$key];
        }
    }

    return $pp;
}
```

Then when you call  the function, do this:

```
$expected_post_keys = array('firstname','lastname');
$safe_post_arr = post_params($expected_post_keys);
extract($safe_post_arr);
```

For $_GET you can take a couple of extra measures like so (you could do it this way for $_POST as well):

```
function get_params($arr){
    // arr predefined explicitly - do not call with _GET as argument
    $gp = array();
    foreach($arr as $key){

        if(isset($_GET[$key])){
            $gp[$key] = htmlspecialchars($_GET[$key]);
        }else{
            $gp[$key] = 0;
        }

    }
    return $gp;
}
```

and when you call the function:

```
$valid_get_keys = array('id','action');
$safe_get_arr = get_params($valid_get_keys);
extract($safe_get_arr );
```

This method gives you every variable/key you expect, but if they aren't defined in $_GET they will have a value of 0.

If you have to do this often, just put both methods in a class and you are automated. Any script where you need to retrieve _GET or _POST you can call the class then call whatever method you need by feeding it the necessary keys.